# binding of ports not working in docker

Tags: docker

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                              COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
2047cd997469        q1           "/bin/bash"            2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          **8001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8001->9001/tcp**   wicket1             
ddb02ced5a0b        q2          "/bin/bash"            28 hours ago        Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp             tender_fermi        
3966528ee466        q3   "/start.sh -D FOREGR   5 days ago          Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp
```

As you can see I have three docker images running everything is working fine except for the image q1 I am not able to run through the port 9001 ..says connection refused. what may be the possible reason. application is working fine inside the container.

**below is the port command:**

```
sudo docker port 2047cd997469
9001/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8001
```

Comment: Can you run "docker port 2047cd997469" and tell us the output?

Comment: Did you mean to use port 8001 on the host? Are you saying inside the container you can access port *9001* on localhost, but from the host you cannot access *8001*? Can you paste the curl or telnet commands showing what does/doesn't work and what you think should happen?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using vagrant or boot2docker? If need to connect 8001 port on your virtual machine. For the boot2docker, you can use `boot2docker ip` to get the ip. For the vagrant, you can use `vagrant ssh` to login and get the ip.